# Cant connect to MySQL DB from Node.js app

Tags: mysql, node.js

im new to `MYSQL` and database programming in general.
using mac im setting the `mysql` server with docker image by running this command:

```
docker run -d --name sql_server_demo -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=123123123' -p 1433:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

the container is running and when i try to connect from command line like so:

```
mssql -u sa -p 123123123
```

it connects successfully and i can start typing queries.
im also able to connect via `Azure Data Studio` as well.

the problem is when im trying to connect from `node.js` app like so:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

const config = {
host: 'localhost',
user: 'sa',
password: 'reallyStrongPwd123',
database: 'logger',
port: '1433',
};

var con = mysql.createConnection(config);

con.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

i specify the port according to the docker `mysql` container and the callback from `connect` never happens. when i delete the port i get this error: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`

any help would be appreciated here:) thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using MsSQL server not MySQL so or you have to change the docker image to mysql (  or use : https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql )
This NPM module 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql